# Cannot find Scanner Class

Tags: java

```
import util.java.Scanner;

class Anagram    
{

public static void main(String args[])
 {
  String s1=new String();

  Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
  s1=s.nextLine();             
 }
}
```

This gives error :

```
cannot find symbol Scanner....
```

whats wrong here?

Comment: I can sense that you are not using an IDE?

Comment: use java.util.Scanner;

Answer (score 4):

The correct import statement is `java.util.Scanner`. 
For avoiding these kind of errors, its good to use and IDE.

Answer (score 3):

The import you have is wrong.

It should be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

instead of

```
import util.java.Scanner;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` class in `java.util.Scanner` package. Import you are using here is incorrect. I suggest you to use IDE to do coding since this kind of issues easily identify by then.